# Why can't I install a Python package with the Python requirement ">=3.8,<3.11" into a Poetry project with the Python version "^3.9"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, dependency-management, python-poetry

I'm having an issue installing dependencies into my Poetry project. If I run `poetry new` (as described in https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/), I can create a new project:

```
$ poetry new scipy-test
Created package scipy_test in scipy-test
```

My project structure looks like this after I delete a few files not needed for this reproduction:

```
$ tree .
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── scipy_test
    └── __init__.py

1 directory, 2 files
```

My `pyproject.toml` file looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "scipy-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I run `poetry add scipy`, it tries to install the latest version of SciPy, which right now is 1.8.1. I get the following error:

```
$ poetry add scipy
Creating virtualenv scipy-test-4EDXm154-py3.9 in /home/mattwelke/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Using version ^1.8.1 for scipy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.9,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - scipy requires Python >=3.8,<3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0
  
  Because no versions of scipy match >1.8.1,<2.0.0
   and scipy (1.8.1) requires Python >=3.8,<3.11, scipy is forbidden.
  So, because scipy-test depends on scipy (^1.8.1), version solving failed.

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For scipy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.9,<3.11"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

I'm interpreting the line `python = "^3.9"` in my `pyproject.toml` file to mean "this project this meant to run with Python 3.9 (any patch version)". And I'm interpreting the package's Python requirement of ">=3.8,<3.11" to mean "this library requires Python 3.8, 3.9, or Python 3.10 to use it". So if I put these two things together, it seems to me like they should be compatible with each other.

The error message does include a hint to help me solve it. It says:

```
For scipy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<3.11"
```

I agree that this would solve the issue. It would make my Poetry project's Python version match the Python requirement of the dependency exactly. I found that if I changed my `pyproject.toml` file this way, I was able to install the dependency.

But I don't want to allow my project to be executed with Python 3.8. I want to set its Python version to the latest version I'm actually using. So my preferred version is actually "^3.10" (if my understanding as described above is correct) because that should mean "you must be using any patch version of Python 3.10 to run this".

If I change the line to `python = "^3.10"`, I get the same kind of error I got before, except the hint in the error message mentions version 3.10 instead of 3.8:

```
For scipy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.10,<3.11"
```

If I use this value, it works again, allowing me to install the dependency. And this time, it looks like it restricts my project to only being compatible with 3.10, as desired. But it looks a bit verbose. I still don't understand why setting it to "^3.9" (or "^3.10") didn't work.

Is there something I'm missing here? If so, how would I change my `pyproject.toml` file to make it compatible with this dependency I want to add to my project?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The caret requirement you specify...

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
```

...means "This Python code has compatibility of `3.9 <= python_version < 4`" (`^` restricts differently based on how you specify the version, using semantic versioning).

This is a wider constraint than what your dependency `scipy` specifies, because it claims only compatibility up to `3.8 <= python_version < 3.11`.

To `poetry`, `scipy` does not meet your constraints because if `python3.11` were out right now, your dependency constraint claims your code supports that Python version, whereas `scipy`'s constraint would say it doesn't.

For you, you probably just want something like a range to match something like `scipy`'s (or narrow your range to fit inside `scipy`'s).

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10, <3.11"
```

Comment: This makes sense. I was misunderstanding what the ^ character meant. I think it's from my experience with Node.js where I'd usually use that with my dependencies because I wanted to express that my project was compatible with new feature versions. Now I realize with Python, I definitely don't want to express that my project is compatible with new feature versions of Python. Those may contain new breaking changes (Python doesn't use semver). I understand now I should use `>=3.10,<3.11` with my project to express that it should only be run with Python 3.11 (any patch version). Thanks!

Comment: @MattWelke I updated my answer slightly to give a constraint range for `3.10.x` since I missed that portion of your original question (it's just the range you mentioned). I _believe_ that you could also use `python = "3.10.*"` as a [wildcard requirement](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#wildcard-requirements) to say you support 3.10 and all patch versions of it.

Comment: Cool. Also I just realized I typoed my comment. Only be run with Python 3.10 (any patch version)*

Comment: Reviewed your answer. And now I noticed this: "(^ restricts differently based on how you specify the version, using semantic versioning)" This *definitely* explains where I went wrong. I was remembering the "^" restricting my Node.js dependencies to accept new patch versions. I never realized its meaning changes if it's used like "^3.10" (accept any minor version) instead of "^3.10.5" (accept any patch version).

Comment: I had this same problem I just use `python="~3.10" ` and all works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

They have answered that the free version is only supported up to python 3.10 until python 3.12 comes out.

https://github.com/polakowo/vectorbt/issues/566#issuecomment-1622923155

They take the paid version of the promotion very seriously. I think even if you could install it, you'd have problems with dependencies like numba on python 3.11.